# How to store two different audios in same m4a file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

I want to accept two mp3 files. These two mp3 files should be stored in the same m4a file (overlayed?) and when that particular m4a file is played both mp3 should be played simultaneously.

I want to play m4a song and determine the path of m4a song on the `UIButton` action. The code for `UIButton` action has been given below.

I have taken two different `AVAudioPlayer` to accept two mp3s and took a single variable (`* audioFileOutput`) to store the destination m4a file.

I have imported two libraries in .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h> 

-(IBAction)playTheSong
{    
    // Path of your source audio file
    NSString *strInputFilePath1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"saewill.mp3"];
    NSString *strInputFilePath2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"kick.mp3"];
    NSURL *audioFileInput1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strInputFilePath1];
    NSURL *audioFileInput2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strInputFilePath2];

    // Path of your destination save audio file
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *libraryCachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *strOutputFilePath = [libraryCachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];
    NSString *requiredOutputPath = [libraryCachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.m4a"];
    NSURL *audioFileOutput = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:requiredOutputPath];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:audioFileOutput error:NULL];
    AVAsset *asset1 = [AVAsset assetWithURL:audioFileInput1];
    AVAsset *asset2 = [AVAsset assetWithURL:audioFileInput2];

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession1 = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset1
                                                                            presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession2 = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset2
                                                                            presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

    //two store two diifrent mp3 in same variable        

    exportSession1.outputURL = audioFileOutput;
    exportSession1.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
    exportSession2.outputURL = audioFileOutput;
    exportSession2.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;

    //initialised AVAudioplayer for 1st mp3.       
    [exportSession1 exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         if (exportSession1.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
         {
             NSLog(@"Success!");
             NSLog(@" OUtput path is \n %@", requiredOutputPath);
             NSFileManager * fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
             [fm moveItemAtPath:strOutputFilePath toPath:requiredOutputPath error:nil];


             NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:requiredOutputPath];
             NSError *error;
             audioPlayer1=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
             audioPlayer1.numberOfLoops=0;
             [audioPlayer1 setVolume:0.75];
             [audioPlayer1 play];


         }
         else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession1.status)
         {
             NSLog(@"failed %@", exportSession1.error.localizedDescription);
         }
     }];

    //initialised AVAudioplayer for 2nd mp3.         

    [exportSession2 exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         if (exportSession2.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
         {
             NSLog(@"Success!");
             NSLog(@" OUtput path is \n %@", requiredOutputPath);
             NSFileManager * fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
             [fm moveItemAtPath:strOutputFilePath toPath:requiredOutputPath error:nil];


             NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:requiredOutputPath];
             NSError *error;
             audioPlayer2=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
             audioPlayer2.numberOfLoops=0;
             [audioPlayer2 setVolume:0.75];
             [audioPlayer2 play];


         }
         else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession2.status)
         {
             NSLog(@"failed %@", exportSession2.error.localizedDescription);
         }
     }];        
}
```

Comment: what is exactly you'd like to achieve? you want to mix those audios in one common file on 'top of each other', or you can to concatenate them into one common file 'one after another'?

Comment: i want to play those two audios simultaneously  and to determine the path on console on the UIButton action.

Comment: i want to mix audios in one common file @holex please help me :(

Comment: supoose there are two audios file:-    1.drum beats   2. guitar playing.    i want to play these two audios simultaneously and there must be a single AVAudioplayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that by yourself, let some iOS audio library help you to implement it, here are two good choices for you:

[EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio)
[TheAmazingAudioEngine](https://github.com/TheAmazingAudioEngine/TheAmazingAudioEngine)

Edit:

In Apple's doc:

> **Playing Multiple Sounds Simultaneously**
>
> To play multiple sounds simultaneously, create one playback audio queue object for each sound. For each audio queue, schedule the first buffer of audio to start at the same time using the AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters function.

You should do it using `audio queue`

Also i think there is a second choice: mix two audio files into a temporary single audio file before invoking AVPlayer every time.

Comment: thanx @Allen i am going to import the library EZAudio TheAmazingAudioEngine

Answer (score 0):

i have done with my problem.

```
as i am new to the ios development so it took much time to obtain the desired result. thanks for your suggestions. 
and here is what i did.



-(void)mixAudio{



CFAbsoluteTime currentTime=CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionAudioTrack setPreferredVolume:0.8];
NSString *soundOne  =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Kick 1" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundOne];
AVAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
NSArray *tracks = [avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];
[compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack1 = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionAudioTrack setPreferredVolume:0.8];
NSString *soundOne1  =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Kick 2" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundOne1];
AVAsset *avAsset1 = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url1 options:nil];
NSArray *tracks1 = [avAsset1 tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack1 = [tracks1 objectAtIndex:0];
[compositionAudioTrack1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset1.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack1 atTime: kCMTimeZero error:nil];




NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryCachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *strOutputFilePath = [libraryCachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];
NSString *requiredOutputPath = [libraryCachesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.m4a"];
NSURL *audioFileOutput = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:requiredOutputPath];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:audioFileOutput error:NULL];



AVAssetExportSession *exporter=[[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
exporter.outputURL=audioFileOutput;
exporter.outputFileType=AVFileTypeAppleM4A;





[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{


    NSLog(@" OUtput path is \n %@", requiredOutputPath);
    NSFileManager * fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    [fm moveItemAtPath:strOutputFilePath toPath:requiredOutputPath error:nil];

     NSLog(@" OUtput path is \n %@", requiredOutputPath);
    NSLog(@"export complete: %lf",CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()-currentTime);
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileOutput error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops=0;
    [audioPlayer play];

}];
```

}